# Multiplicity of orbitals in a magnetic field

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Solving past questions preparing for a test, I am stuck at number 11. Is multiplicity the ml value[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$m_l$ is the magnetic quantum number, and *multiplicity* refers to the number of allowed values that $m_l$ can be.

Comment: I found strange the text "in a magnetic field".

Comment: @user1420303 Why? In an atom, an applied electric field will only shift the energy levels, not split them. You need an applied magnetic field to do that.

Comment: I agree with your answer.  But the number of allowed values for $m_l$ (for some $l$) is 2$l$+1 when no magnetic field is applied. As the typical hydrogen atom case. In presence of an external magnetic field there would be further lost of degeneracy. That is why I do not get why to state "in a magnetic field" in 11.
I would not say that there is not split of energy levels in presence of an electric field (for example, crystal field theory).

Comment: I was overthinking it; just because the energy does or doesn't change has no affect on the allowed values. I was also only thinking of the electric dipole approximation between p orbitals. But yes, it is more general than "in a magnetic field".